# Jekyll does not parse UTF-8

Tags: encoding, jekyll

I created a page in notepad and selected UTF-8 as the encoding while saving. Jekyll does not parse this page. It renders the liquid extensions in the page as they are.

Now I saved the same page using ANSI encoding. Jekyll parses that easily and my site is up and running. But it is limited only to ANSI and some characters appear as a question mark due to wrong encoding. I do not want to use ANSI instead of UTF-8 when the web fully supports it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be due to the fact that Notepad inserts a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) (BOM) at the beginning of UTF-8 documents, which may interfere with their processing (especially by tools that are aimed primarily at Unix). You could try using another text editor (or stripping out the BOM with another tool may work).